# Double border coming in every row of table

Tags: css, html-table

There is a table which I have given border. After giving border there were double border that were coming after some googling I found that border-collapse is my saviour. but after trying to use it in every possible way it is not working.

There is a double border at the bottom that is coming that I want to remove.

For better understanding attached screen shot:

[image]

I want to remove the double border coming after each cell.

Markup.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th >
             Login Name
         </th>
         <th>
             SheetName
         </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
       <td>aaa</td>
       <td>abc</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>asdfasdf</td>
       <td>aasdfsadfbc</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add the CSS styles as well.

Comment: In which browser are you testing ? Seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/cLnFE/) in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: it is attached as a template in an email

Comment: @VimalStan no css class has been applied on this

Comment: hey, if you run the markup that you have pasted here, directly on an html page, there are no double borders. it has to do with something else on your original code. look out for possible global css classes applied to table element. look out if some invalid markup is not there!!

Comment: @ManishMishra it is a mail template that is getting attached in the mail that it is being sent... can you suggest something if it was in browser that what css can be applied to remove this.

Comment: so open your mail in browser, inspect element the table and see what classes are being applied to it. then come back to your code and modify those classes. That's all i can say, without looking at the full markup

Comment: Setting an inline style of `border: 1px solid black` should work. I recommend inline styles because not all email clients support internal/external styles.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is needed to provide a definite answer. As others said, make sure there aren't any global CSS files altering your HTML. It appears your CSS has a `tr {margin-top:10px;}` set in it, or something providing a similar effect.

Just out of curiosity, why are you using the HTML cellpadding attribute? The CSS padding attribute can perform the same function and provides much more flexibility. You will also find separating your styles (CSS) from your HTML will make changing and updating much easier than going back to modify each inline style.

```
<table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th >
                    Login Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    SheetName
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
<tr><td>aaa</td><td>abc</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdfasdf</td><td>aasdfsadfbc</td></tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
#table {
   padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
   //this is shortand for top right bottom left
   border-collapse: collapse;
   //this is becoming deprecated and is mainly used to support older versions of IE
}
```